# Drive Rest API doesnot list a particular folder

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

I am using v2 api of drive to get all files of my drive folder. One particular folder is not coming in the list.All others are there. It is a starred folder whose previous owner was someone else.

Following is my request:

```
var options = {

    method: 'GET',
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files",
    qs: {
        q: "parents=\'" + parent_id + "\'ANDmimeType=\'application/vnd.google-apps.folder\'",
        pageToken: nextPageToken
    },
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    }
};
```

I have added pagination, still the folder is not coming. Not sure of the reason. This folder is visible when I open my drive.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the response you are getting and note what you think is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with i would sugest that you have an error your missing a space between `and` and `mimetype`

```
q: "parents=\'" + parent_id + "\'AND mimeType != \'application/vnd.google-apps.folder\'",
```

It can be easier to test your search parm in the [apis explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.files.list?q=+sharedWithMe%253Dtrue+and+mimeType+%253D+'application%252Fvnd.google-apps.folder'&_h=3&) it can be tricky.

After testing i found this works.

```
sharedWithMe=true and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
```

formatted gives you

```
sharedWithMe%3Dtrue+and+mimeType+%3D+'application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder'
```

Comment: I did try with the space now, still the issue remains. I cant see a few files and folders

Comment: What about without your search?

Comment: I was able to check that it is a shared folder. so I updated my querystring:


            q: 'sharedWithMe=trueANDmimeType=\'application/vnd.google-apps.folder\'',
         


Still thie folder is not showing. I figured the reason: This particular folder has a missing property 'sharedWithMeDate'. Any thoughts now?

Comment: sharedWithMe=true and mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'